# Python - Getting the intersection of two Json-Files

Tags: python, json

i'm looking for an option to calculate the intersection of two JSON-Files. I have been searching for it and found that i can use sets for my problem. This works "okay". But i have to get a more detailed view of the intersection. And this is where the problems are starting.

**How i calc the intersection:**

```
def calcIntersect(ValidationFile, json_object1, json_object2):

with open(ValidationFile) as schema_file:
    schema = j.load(schema_file)
    js.Draft4Validator.check_schema(schema)

with open(json_object1) as spec_file:
    spec1 = j.load(spec_file, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
    js.validate(spec1, schema)

with open(json_object2) as spec_file:
    spec2 = j.load(spec_file, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
    js.validate(spec2, schema)

x = set(spec1) & set(spec2)

print(x)
```

**Example Data1:**

```
{
    "Car":{
        "Brand":"Audi",
        "Nationality":"Germany",
        "Modelname":"A6"
    },
    "Engine":{
        "cubic capacity":"2967",
        "Enginetype":"V6",
        "Fuel":"Diesel",
        "MaxSpeed":"250"

    },
    "Colors":{
        "Carcolor":"Black",
        "Interiorrcolor":"white"
    }
}
```

**Example Data2:**

```
{
    "Car":{
        "Brand":"Audi",
        "Nationality":"USA",
        "Modelname":"A6"
    },
    "Engine":{
        "cubic capacity":"2995",
        "Enginetype":"V6",
        "Fuel":"Petrol",
        "MaxSpeed":"250"

    },
    "Colors":{
        "Carcolor":"Black",
        "Interiorrcolor":"Black"
    }
}
```

**Example-Output:**

```
{'Car', 'Colors', 'Engine'}
```

This are just the "Keys" but i need the dictonaries. At the moment it is giving me this keys to say that there is a intersection in it. Maybe in 'Car' there is in both Files a "Audi" and the nationality is different because one car is produced in America and the other car is produced in Germany. But still it returns 'Car' and not the "Audi".

I hope i were able to describe my problem for a bit. It's my first question..

Comment: It would help to understand if we knew example data of spec1 / spec2

Comment: @user2358582 Okay edited it and added Example-Data which descripes the situation. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following lines, inspired by @likeon's answer, will give you a dictionary whose keys will be the keys of the intersecting objects in your specs, and the values an array containing the intersecting objects.

```
intersect = { key: [o, spec2[key]] for key, o in spec1.iteritems()
                                   if key in spec2 };
```

**Edit**:
If you are using *python 3*, you must use `items`instead of `iteritems`:

```
intersect = { key: [o, spec2[key]] for key, o in spec1.items()
                                   if key in spec2 };
```

Comment: Okay i think i got displayed a "default" solution. Thanks! I will try this out.

Comment: Okay i tested it. Works fine. Thank you very much! For people who use Python 3.x you have to change "spec1.iteritems()" to "spec1.items()"

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't just iterate over spec1 and compare values with spec2 like that:

```
x = {k: v for k, v in spec1.iteritems() if k in spec2 and spec2[k] == v}
```

Comment: This is what i'm planing to use at the moment. But i think/thought there will be better options. Thank you!

Comment: This will return all the values though, not the matching elements only! and will raise an keyerror exception if thek is not found on spec2.

Comment: Not exactly, it will return only the values of `spec1`. I took the liberty to fork your code so it returns both values.

Comment: @YOBA Yes, the example code but the idea is right to iterate over all elements and compare them.

Comment: Ok then, if this is what you looked for, just use spec2.get(k) == v instead, to avoid keyerror exception.

Comment: @YOBA Here is may be a situation when spec1 has a key with None value and spec doest not. In this case the key whould be shown in intersection but for real it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a recursive solution:

```
json1 = {
    "Car": {
        "Brand": "Audi",
        "Nationality": "Germany",
        "Modelname": "A6"
    },
    "Engine": {
        "cubic capacity": "2967",
        "Enginetype": "V6",
        "Fuel": "Diesel",
        "MaxSpeed": "250"
    },
    "Colors": {
        "Carcolor": "Black",
        "Interiorrcolor": "white"
    }
}

json2 = {
    "Car": {
        "Brand": "Audi",
        "Nationality": "USA",
        "Modelname": "A6"
    },
    "Engine": {
        "cubic capacity": "2995",
        "Enginetype": "V6",
        "Fuel": "Petrol",
        "MaxSpeed": "250"
    },
    "Colors": {
        "Carcolor": "Black",
        "Interiorrcolor": "Black"
    }
}


def common_dict(d1, d2):
    output = {}
    for k in set(d1) & set(d2):
        o1, o2 = d1[k], d2[k]
        if isinstance(o1, dict) and isinstance(o2, dict):
            output[k] = common_dict(o1, o2)
        elif o1 == o2:
            output[k] = o1
    return output

print common_dict(json1, json2)
# {'Engine': {'MaxSpeed': '250', 'Enginetype': 'V6'}, 'Car': {'Brand': 'Audi', 'Modelname': 'A6'}, 'Colors': {'Carcolor': 'Black'}}
```

Comment: Becoming a "TypeError: string indices must be integers" at the line where you define o1 and o2.

Comment: What do you pass to common_dict?

Comment: Three Files. A Shemefile and two Json-Files.

Comment: @DomeA. common_dict takes two arguments. How are you passing three objects there? And what is a 'json file'. Is it a file object? Python dict? String object? It should be a Python dictionary.

Comment: Yes. I'm passing two objects there sorry. But Two file-objects. But i have a solution now. I'm iterating threw the elements. Like Quentin adviced me. I will test it now. But Thanks for your solution i will try it out too.